# The "Total Indexed" is always zero in Google Webmaster Tools despite it showing some of the sitemap is indexed

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I'm a newbie in Google Webmaster Tools. I've verified my site, created my sitemap and submitted it to the google webmaster account.

But after a week of waiting I've found that 46 out of 250 URLs in my sitemap are indexed (optimization -> sitemaps) but the Total Indexed is always a zero?

Is this normal or do I have to do something else?

Comment: I would have thought your "total indexed" figure should be at least as high as the number indexed from the sitemap? And certainly greater than 1 if _anything_ is indexed, even if all your pages are duplicate! Are you looking at the correct version of your site... ie. With or without the `www` subdomain?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with my site, it's made with drupal7 and no error appeared according to the Crawl errors page

Comment: But which site are you looking at in GWT - `yourdomain.com` or `www.yourdomain.com`? Which is the canonical domain?

Comment: i've insered www.mydomaine.com

Comment: is that a wrong url?

Comment: If your site is setup to be accessed via `www` (only) and GWT is set for `www` then that is OK.

Comment: So what 's the problem?

Comment: in another way, i have a personal pages and data and i still have the zero

Comment: If you search for `site:yourdomain.com` in Google search, does it return indexed pages? How many? The same as in your XML sitemap?

Comment: Yes it does, and it's about 2700 results

Answer (score 1):

Google Webmaster Tools can be uber slow (at least it was in 2012), especially if your site does not have many backlinks or if it is not crawled often.