# “See Index Coverage” link from sitemap not working in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, coverage

Why is my “See Index Coverage” button is disabled? I created the property 2 months ago and also submitted sitemap then. I still can't see my index coverage for the sitemaps I submitted.

[image]

Comment: How many URLs are supposed to be in the sitemap, is it really only 4?   People have recently reported that Google is being very slow about discovering all the URLs in sitemaps.  It sometimes takes many months.   It could be that the index coverage is going to take that long as well.  See [The “Total Indexed” is always zero in Google Webmaster Tools despite it showing some of the sitemap is indexed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35281/the-total-indexed-is-always-zero-in-google-webmaster-tools-despite-it-showing)

Comment: See also: [Google says my sitemap index was “processed successfully”, yet “total discovered URLs” is 0](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126430/google-says-my-sitemap-index-was-processed-successfully-yet-total-discovered)