# Why is my coverage empty google search / index console

Tags: google-search

I successfully added my site map .
I successfully inspected my homepage in the inspector.
But its been like 8 hours and still my "coverage" tab is empty and I can't google myself yet

Comment: Maybe this answers my question. Because google are slow pokes. [https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129051/see-index-coverage-link-from-sitemap-not-working-in-google-search-console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129051/see-index-coverage-link-from-sitemap-not-working-in-google-search-console)

Comment: 8 hours?  You need to give Google at least two weeks.  If your site is brand new it could even take a few months.